# How to create a two column div that grows with contents?

Tags: php, jquery, css

My aim is to create two columns that grows automatic. The problem is that I want to compare column 1 to column2.
(i.e) if col1 contents > col2 contents add a content to col2 else if col1==col2 add next content to col1 until all unknown contents amount are laid out.
How can I keep track of the contents in the columns so that to compare the two columns?

It would look something like this, instead of numbers the would be characters

[image: image to help explain my aim]

Comment: Please define how to measure the size of contents that is added to a column. Please define the nature of a single content and how you can create contents (plural) out of content (singular). Please define column as per outpupt. Basically your questions sounds very complicated and too broad to be actually answered. Maybe you can improve it and it will attract more users answering it.

Answer (score 0):

if your content is plain text use jquery to do that with two class (col1 and col2):

```
    var co1=$('.col1').val();
    var co2=$('.col2').val();
    if(co1.length > co2.length)
    {
       $('.col1').append('some html');
    }else if(co1.length <= co2.length){
       $('.col2').append('some html'); 
    }
```

in other case you can do this method too.